# How do i check if the numbers in my JTable Column is lesser than a specified no and display only that particular row

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to loop through a column in my Jtable after performing the sql code to get the particular column i.e

```
String sql = "Select Age From StudentTable";
```

Here Age is a Column on the StudentTable and i'm searching for ages below and above a particular age, then display the corresponding rows only.
How do i go about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i finally figured this out. All i needed was an SQL statement

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM StudentTable WHERE Age > '"+yourintegervariable+"'";
```

and that was it.